# webpack dev server doesn't recognize JSX code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get a React project running with webpack-dev-server. The project runs, but when I start the dev server with `yarn run webpack-dev-server`, I get the following message:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/components/index.jsx 9:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
|   );
>   root.render(<App />);
| });
```

What am I missing from my toolchain? The full repo is available here:
https://github.com/fredwillmore/billboard

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question itself. Do you think you do have a loader for JSX?

Comment: Youre missing the toolchain to transpile JSX to JS. Webpack wont handle it natively without plugins, it's only a bundler and not a transpiler.  You could do it with `babel-loader` and `@babel/preset-react` but you're probably better off with [SWC](https://swc.rs/docs/usage/swc-loader) nowadays (easier to configure, much much faster). Just enable JSX as well: https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/compilation

Comment: Also, a more left-field answer but I notice you use esbuild for production. It'd be kind of a pain to be managing 2 toolchains for dev and prod (and possibly problematic). Vite gives you a single configuration point for prod and dev and uses esbuild under the hood already...though notably only for transpilation and not for bundling (uses rollup for that). Its rapid though.

Comment: I just realised actually you could and probably should for consistencies sake use https://github.com/privatenumber/esbuild-loader instead.

Comment: @adsy I am using esbuild but only because the tutorial I was following used it. But I think it's the right tool because it takes care of all the transpiling that babel used to do. I'd like to get rid of webpack altogether, but I want the webpack-dev-server. I might see if I can just use pin/importmaps to manage the JS dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just wasn't looking far enough - using babel to transpile JSX is the next step:

```
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

create ./babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ]
};
```

update ./webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/javascript/components/index.jsx',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```